# user input with file I/O in python

Tags: python, io

Was wondering if I could user input the name of a .txt file when "opening" a file. Because right now, when I enter a name I have the problem that I can't append the .txt suffix to it so it doesn't create a .txt file. here:

```
name = input("enter a name: ")    
text1 = open(name,"wt")
```

so how can I append the .txt suffix? Since both the input and the open method only take a limited amount of arguments?

Answer (score 4):

To concatenate strings in Python, use `+`:

```
text1 = open(name + ".txt", "wt")
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use string formatting, either old or new-style.

Old style:

```
text1 = open('%s.txt' % (name,), 'wt')
```

New style:

```
text1 = open('{}.txt'.format(name), 'wt')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the concatenation of strings operator to join the name of the file and the suffix.

Something like name + ".txt" should give you name.txt in a string format

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use raw_input to get a string as well.

Comment: That's true for Python 2. In Python 3, `input()` is the correct function.